# Accessing the numbers entered in a file along with its index

Tags: python, file

I am making a program where i need to access the data stored in file along with index number. For example,
lets say i take 5 inputs from user and save it in file.

```
with open("test file.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(5):
        data = input()
        file.write(f"{data}\n")
```

Now, at a later time i want to be able to access the the data and change it depending on its index(0 for the first number etc)

```
with open("test file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data[0])
```

But the problem is `data[0]` actually gives me the first literal number in the data and not the number entered by the user(gives 1 if the number entered by the user was 123). So my question is how do i index the numbers according to the number user enters and not each indivisual numbers. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the lines rather than the string of all the data.

```
with open("test file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    lines = data.split('\n')
    print(lines[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = [int(n.strip()) for n in file.readlines()]
    print(data[0])
```